# Office 365: Organization Unit

Tags: active-directory, office365, ou

I need to know how I can

> > > Retrieve all organization units for my tenant (Azure AD)
> > >
> > > Fetch users for belonging to a certain Organization Unit.

Is there any REST API documentation for this purpose? Let's say if I need to access the data for my tenant users belonging to a certain OU, where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any REST API documentation for this purpose?

**Organization Unit** is a concept in on-premise Windows Active Directory. Organizational units are Active Directory **containers** into which you can place users, groups, computers, and other organizational units.

Azure AD is a cloud based identity service, unlike the Windows domain service, there is no concept named "Organization Unit". I'm afraid there is no such REST API to query user which the Organization Units he belongs to.

For new feature requests about Azure Active Directory, you can submit your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).